# Error when importing csv data into R for text mining

Tags: r, tm, tidytext

I keep getting this error when trying to import a csv document into R and trying to develop a corpus for topic modeling. I have used this approach successfully on 4 other projects but cannot get past this error.
My data source has a doc_id column and a text column. Error is 
Error:

> all(!is.na(match(c("doc_id", "text"), names(x)))) is not TRUE

I tried importing using a a number of different suggestions such as 
[Error faced while using TM package's VCorpus in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406555/error-faced-while-using-tm-packages-vcorpus-in-r)

```
file_loc <- "C:\\Users\\mdlawrence\\Desktop\\Test2.csv "

 x <- read.csv(file_loc, header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = F)

 require(tm)
 Loading required package: tm

 Loading required package: NLP

 corp <- Corpus(DataframeSource(x))
```

> Error: all(!is.na(match(c("doc_id", "text"), names(x)))) is not TRUE

```
docs <- DocumentTermMatrix(corp)
```

> Error in TermDocumentMatrix(x, control) : object 'corp' not found

I expect to see a corpus with one document per row in the .csv file. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you add a sample of `x` with `head(x)` or better a `dput`?

Comment: As far as I remember with the `tm` package the column names must be `doc_id` and `text`. What is the column name of the `text` part? Try also `VCorpus(DataframeSource(x))`. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406555/error-faced-while-using-tm-packages-vcorpus-in-r  which seems to have the same problem as you face.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error faced while using TM package's VCorpus in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47406555/error-faced-while-using-tm-packages-vcorpus-in-r)

Comment: @NelsonGon structure(list(X.doc_id. = c("1A", "2A",…
), 

X.text. = c("I think a conversation needs to be had to bring all employee groups up to the same … 0 feet"

)), .

Names = c("X.doc_id.", "X.text."), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-100L))

Comment: @NelsonGon also when I try the solution presented in the possible duplicate problem I get this error. Error in data.frame(doc_id = row.names(xdata), text = x$text) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 100, 0

Comment: @user113156 the column name is text. I saw that post which is why I changed the column names. I am at a loss. Thank you for your input.

Comment: You can [edit] the question to include a `dput` of a representative sample of the data. One row isn't enough to test out your code on. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R post folks can more easily help with.

Answer (score 1):

Its a name issue with your column names. The `dput` you provide shows this also (`X.doc_id`) and (`X.text`). So running the following produces the same error as you were experiencing.

```
x <- structure(list(X.doc_id. = c("1A", "2A"), 
                    X.text. = c("I think a conversation needs to be had to bring all employee groups up to the same … 0 feet" )),
               .Names = c("X.doc_id.", "X.text."), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))


library(tm)
VCorpus(DataframeSource(x))
```

> Error in inherits(x, "Source") :    all(!is.na(match(c("doc_id",
>   "text"), names(x)))) is not TRUE

Running the following gets the correct result you are looking for.

```
colnames(x) <- c("doc_id", "text") 
library(tm)
Y <- VCorpus(DataframeSource(x))
Y
```

> <> Metadata:  corpus specific: 0, document level (indexed): 0
>   Content:  documents: 10

Running:

```
content(Y)
content(Y[[1]])
```

Gives:

> > content(Y[[1]]) [1] "I think a conversation needs to be had to bring all employee groups up to the same … 0 feet"

Creating the `documenttermmatrix`:

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(Y)
dtm
```

> <> Non-/sparse entries:
>   11/99 Sparsity           : 90% Maximal term length: 12 Weighting
>   : term frequency (tf)

Somewhere in your code or loading in the data you may have had duplicate column names and reading in the data automatically creates an `X.doc_id` column to prevent duplicate column names.