# Error in nchar(Terms(x), type = "chars") : invalid multibyte string, element 204, when inspecting document term matrix

Tags: r, text-mining

Here is the source code that I have used:

```
 MyData <- Corpus(DirSource("F:/Data/CSV/Data"),readerControl = list(reader=readPlain,language="cn"))
    SegmentedData <- lapply(MyData, function(x) unlist(segmentCN(x)))
    temp <- Corpus(DataframeSource(SegmentedData), readerControl = list(reader=readPlain, language="cn"))
```

#### Preprocessing Data

```
temp <- tm_map(temp, removePunctuation)
temp <- tm_map(temp,removeNumbers)
removeURL <- function(x)gsub("http[[:alnum:]]*"," ",x)
temp <- tm_map(temp, removeURL)
temp <- tm_map(temp,stripWhitespace)
dtmxi <- DocumentTermMatrix(temp)
dtmxi <- removeSparseTerms(dtmxi,0.83)

**inspect(t(dtmxi))** ---This is where I get the error
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are some Chinese characters in your file. To overcome this issue, use this line of code to read them as well:

```
Sys.setlocale('LC_ALL','C')
```

Answer (score 0):

My `RStudio` restarts the session after to set `Sys.setlocale( 'LC_ALL','C' )` and run the `TermDocumentMatrix( mycorpus )` function.

Answer (score 0):

u can use this code:
txt <- tm_map (txt, content_transformer(stemDocument))
txt is ur text vector.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).